# Configure Varnish backend in kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm experimenting with spinning up a Varnish instance to speed up a slow but static endpoint of a service. The service is already running in a Kubernetes cluster so I'm basing the setup on the official docker image and following the advice of baking the VCL file into the image:

```
FROM varnish:6.2

COPY default.vcl /etc/varnish/
```

I'm starting with a small amount of configuration in `default.vcl`:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
        .host = "172.17.0.1:8018"; # IP for local experimentation
}

# only cache '/v1/xyz/...'
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/v1/xyz/") {
        return (hash);
    }
    return (pass);
}
```

I would like to be able to declare the target backend in the deployment file, either using env vars or cli args.

The `-b` flag seemed perfect for the job, but fails with `Error: Only one of -b or -f can be specified`.

And using `std.getenv` in the `backend` block doesn't work either:

```
import std;

backend default {
        .host = std.getenv("VARNISH_TAGET_HOST");
}
```

results in

```
Expected CSTR got 'std'
(program line 369), at
('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 6 Pos 17)
        .host = std.getenv("VARNISH_TAGET_HOST");
----------------###------------------------------
```

Is there some way (not including `sed`-like hacks) by which I can configure the backend without hardcoding it into the VCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Varnish Enterprise has dynamic backends

*Varnish Cache*, the open source version of Varnish, only allows static backend definitions.

The only way you can define backends *on-the-fly*, is by using *Varnish Enterprise*, the commercial version of the software.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/ for more information about the *dynamic backends* feature.

### Why -b & -f cannot be combined

Apparently the `-b` parameter is a shorthand for the following command:

```
varnishadm vcl.inline boot << EOF
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "<addr>";
}
EOF
```

So in fact `-b` already creates and loads *VCL* in the background, which makes this option mutually exclusive with `-f`

Comment: If by "on-the-fly" you mean on runtime then that's not what I need. I know the backend on boot time, I would just like to configure it as a parameter instead of having it hardcoded.

Comment: The only way around this is with a VCL pre-processor: some script that replaces a placeholder in the backend definition of your VCL file before `varnishd` is booted.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know if that's an intentional limitation, i.e. why I can't just use `-b` and `-f` together?

Comment: I'll look into it asap.

Comment: I edited my answer, and added some more information about the mutual exclusivity of `-b` & `-f`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It would be nice if it was able to also inject it into the top of a provided VCL though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225359/discussion-between-thijs-feryn-and-halle-knast).